# gradleBuild pass properties back to caller during evaluation

Tags: gradle, build, task

build.gradle

```
task foo(type: GradleBuild) {
    dir = '/foo'
    tasks = ['foo']
}

println foo.version
```

/foo/build.gradle

```
project.ext {
    version = "1.0"
}
```

How to pass a property(e.g. version) defined in "/foo/build.gradle" back during evaluation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't be possible. The functionality of the `GradleBuild` task is limited, you can't even read the output of the Gradle invocation via the public API.

But, if your builds are connected, you should include the `foo` project as subproject of your parent project. Simply include the project in your `settings.gradle` file (you can create one if it does not exist):

```
include ':foo'
```

Now, if you invoke gradle, the entered tasks will be executed in your root project as well as in your `foo` project (if existent). You can let tasks of your root project depend on tasks of your `foo` project by using:

```
myRootTask.dependsOn ':foo:myFooTask'
```